# How to handle keypress events in a Kendo grid detailTemplate

Tags: events, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, keypress

I have a Kendo grid with a detailTemplate (textarea with some styling) and am trying to intercept and handle a keypress event.

I have tried AngularJS and jQuery patterns with no luck.

If anybody has been successful I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  detailTemplate: kendo.template( $("#template" ).html()),
  detailInit: detailInit
});

function detailInit(e) {
  var detailRow = e.detailRow;
    var txtArea = detailRow.find(".myTextArea");
    $(txtArea).on("keypress", function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="gid"></div>
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <textarea class="myTextArea"></textarea>  
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I can't seem to get your snippet to work http://jsfiddle.net/AlanPainter/jhgaL80e/

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the control characters such as CR or Tab, then also listen to the KeyDown event.

```
function detailInit(e) {
  var detailRow = e.detailRow;

  detailRow.find(".myTextArea").on("keypress", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
  detailRow.find(".myTextArea").on("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```